# Android Execute code before OS kills my app

Tags: android, kill-process, taskkill

When I press Home button my app goes in background (i.e `onPause()` and `onStop()` methods called).

Now If I keep app in background for longer time with my phone in idle state then OS kills the app after some time.

Now what I want to do is execute some code just before my app is getting killed by OS.

Can anyone tells me how can I do that?

Comment: you should use onPause() and onStop() ... there is no onJustBeforeGetKilled

Comment: Yeah I know that there is no such methods, but looking for if there is any workaround to achieve this.

Comment: you can nullify your obejcts , close threads in onDestroy()